# Invalid value promise pending in sequelize seeder

Tags: node.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to run this simple seeder.
This error occurs when I use the hash function. Runs correctly without function.

How do I hash my password?

```
 'use strict';
  const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

  async function hash(password) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const passwprdHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);  

    return passwprdHash;
  }

  module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
        email: 'info@admin.ir',
        username: 'admin',
        password: hash('secret'),
        name: 'admin',
        family: 'admin',
        mobile: '000000',
        about: 'Fullstack webdeveloper',
        active: true,
        permission_group_id: 1,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date()
      }]);
    },

    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
    }
  };
```

Error is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to `await` the hash function as it is async. somethng like this

```
'use strict';
  const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

  async function hash(password) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const passwprdHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);  

    return passwprdHash;
  }

  module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
        email: 'info@admin.ir',
        username: 'admin',
        password: await hash('secret'),
        name: 'admin',
        family: 'admin',
        mobile: '000000',
        about: 'Fullstack webdeveloper',
        active: true,
        permission_group_id: 1,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date()
      }]);
    },

    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
    }
  };
```

Comment: The error changed to this " ERROR: Unexpected identifier" @ashish-modi